# How to perform an action just before and after the animation

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-animation

I want to perform some actions just before and just after an animation.
Here is my code:-

```
AnimatorSet set1 = new AnimatorSet();
set1.playTogether(
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ball1, "translationX", x1, xn),
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ball1, "translationY", y1, yn),
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ball2, "translationX", xn, x1),
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ball2, "translationY", yn, y1)

);
set1.setDuration(1000).start();
```

Is there any animator set method to do that.??

Comment: You want to perform an action between animations? or just after all of them have finished?

Comment: @zozelfelfo  After all of them have finished.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **setAnimationListener** for this:

```
set.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //code when starting animation
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //code on animation end
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: @ShivamGupta see my updated answer I am using a different listener than before